# Adding a space between words in mathjax within rshiny

Tags: r

I want to add a space between the words "petrol" and "price" in the fraction below, can anyone show me how this can be done?

I have only been able to find how to separate individual fractions and not just words.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$style(HTML("
                    div.MathJax_Display{
                    text-align: left !important;
                    }
  ")),
    fluidRow(column(width = 5,
        uiOutput("formula"))))

server <- function(input,output){
  output$formula <- renderUI({
    withMathJax("$$\\frac{petrol price}{mpg}$$")
  })
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\\`  like this.

```
withMathJax("$$\\frac{petrol\\ price}{mpg}$$")
```

[image]